# addition in while( )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
   <textarea id="input1"></textarea>
   <textarea id="input2"></textarea>
   <span></span>
</form>
```

the js:

```
$("#input2").keyup{
 var a = document.getElementById("input1").length;
 var b = document.getElementById("input2").length;
 var c=a+b;
  $("span").html(c);
}
```

each time 'c' reach multiple 140, i need it to be added by 'b',
I've try to do this:

```
while(c%140 == 0){
   c=c+b;
}
```

at 140th keyup, yes its added, but next keyup(141th) and so on 'c' back to it's value added by notihng. How to do this correctly?

thanks.

Comment: Where is that while loop in the context of the other code? You're resetting c with every key-up on #input2. I have no real idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Arun [I did](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/kckyx/)

Comment: yes, like Austin did except $("span").html(c), sorry the question just editted. thank to all anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure that I'm reading this question correctly, but if [my jsfiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/kckyx/) is a close approximation, the solution may be as simple as getting rid of the `var` in front of `c` when you add `a+b`. If you want `c` to have a persistant value, you need its scope to be outside the `keyup` event handler.

From the fiddle:

```
$(function() {
   var c = 0;

   $("#input2").keyup( function() {
       var a = $("#input1").val().length;
       var b = $("#input2").val().length;
       c=a+b;
       if(c%140 == 0){
           c=c+b;
       }
       $("span").html(b);
   });

});
```

Notice that's an `if`, not a `while`. If it's supposed to be a while loop, that's an easy change to make.

### Update

I think I have an idea what's going on here. You want to keep track of the total character count of your multi-page SMS messages. The [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/kckyx/5/) has the answer to the question you wouldn't just come out and ask.

Here's the new code:

```
$(function() {

  $("#input2, #input1").keyup( function() {
    var a = $("#input1").val().length;
    var b = $("#input2").val().length;
    c=a+b;

    c+=Math.floor(c/140)*b;

    $("span").html(c); 
  });

});
```

Now, this of course assumes that input1 holds your actual message while input2 holds some text that needs to be displayed on each page.  If it's the other way around, or if there's some other purpose for this code, please let me know.